# Is there a way to read the options before use the mergeOptions function in react native navigation v2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation-v2

Is there a way to read the options before using the mergeOptions function.
I'm trying to add a sideMenu that opens and closes with the same button. But to handle that logic, Instead of making use of redux, I want to read the options before the merge, so I can simply do something like `visible: !pastVisible`.

```
navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
        sideMenu: {
            'left': {
                visible: false
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(`Se presiono ${buttonId}`);
}
```

So basically I want to read the value of the visible option before changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, I can only achieve this using redux.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleSideMenu } from './../../store/actions/index';

class SideDrawer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Navigation.events().registerComponentDidDisappearListener(({ componentId }) => {
            this.props.toggleSideMenu(false);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is the sidedrawer</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleSideMenu: (visible) => dispatch(toggleSideMenu(visible))
    };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SideDrawer);
```

Then I just add the listeners to the sidemenu component. Depending on the case, I update the current state of the component (visible or not).

Finally on the components where I want to use the side drawer button I just implement the `navigationButtenPressed` method. Then I just call the reducer to know the current visible state and toggled it.

```
navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    const visible = !this.props.sideMenu;
    Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
        sideMenu: {
            'left': {
                visible: visible
            }
        }
    });
    this.props.toggleSideMenu(visible);
}
```

If there is a more easy way to achieve this I'll be glad to know about it.